# Implicit Euler for Mass Spring System

Tags: c++, eigen, cgal

I am currently working on implementing Implicit Euler on a Simulation software for a School project, and I have a hard time wrapping my head around implicit Euler formulas for a Mass Spring System and more specifically, the Jacobian Matrix computation and the final formula that needs to be solved.

As I am new to stack overflow, I apologize beforehand if I posted this in the wrong section or if there are any errors.

What I implemented so far produces weird results (Unrealistic simulations, explosions etc...).
So if you guys could point out anything I didn't get right I would be immensely grateful.

Here is what I think I understood :

- There are two Jacobian Matrices, one for the Spring Stretch Force and one for the Spring Damping, both following this structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUQ0J.jpg (With N the number of particles in the system)
- Each particle Jacobian is computed the following formulas :

  - For the Stretch force Jacobian Matrix :

`δfi/δxj = ks⋅uij⋅uTij`

`uTij` is the transpose of the vector `uij` (Sorry if the formulas are not very readable)

(This is actually not the full formula found in the sources, but my teacher told me I could implement this one at first)

- For the Damping force Jacobian Matrix :

`δfi/δxj=kd⋅uij⋅uTij`

- `kd` and `ks` are respectively the damping and the stiffness of the spring.
- uij the vector between the two particles of the spring.
- As for the diagonals of both the matrices, I saw that it was the sum of all the particle jacobians connected to that particle so : 
  `δfi/δxi=∑jδfiδxj`, but I am really unsure about this one.
  Connected particles have `δfi/δxj=−δfj/δxi`

Here is an exemple of the weird explosions I talked about :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Xzx.jpg

And here are the sources I read if that could help: http://blog.mmacklin.com/2012/05/04/implicitsprings/ http://hugi.scene.org/online/hugi28/hugi%2028%20-%20coding%20corner%20uttumuttu%20implementing%20the%20implicit%20euler%20method%20for%20mass-spring%20systems.htm

Thank you for your time !

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: *So if you guys could point out anything I didn't get right* -- Why haven't you used your debugger?  You know what the values should be, and you have the entire program you wrote available to you.  That is all a programmer needs to solve the problem on their own.

Comment: I am sorry my question wasn't clear enough, I am actually asking if the formulas and the ways to compute the Jacobians are right.

Comment: And yes I did use the debugger and found out the values for the forces and matrices used in general gets horribly wrong after a couple of timesteps, but I don't know from where the problem could be coming from, which is why I just want to know if the mathematical formulas part is right.

Comment: Your damping force is certainly wrong (supposing uij are position coordinates). The damping force depends on the velocity. So you have a system without damping. I am not an expert in numerical method but the scheme you use is probably unstable without damping. You could check what happen if you set kd to 0 and decrease your time step by 1 or 2 or more order of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check that out and keep you updated

Comment: It is impossible to answer why your code does not work without having a code.

Comment: If your question is about the formulas, perhaps try [math.se] or [physics.se]. This site primarily focuses on actual implementations.

Comment: Well I actually already posted on mathematics but there wasn't much response there and I thought that since this is a field closely related to computer Graphics that maybe someone here would have experience dealing with this kind of problems